# Why is iBeacon not triggering entry & exit events since release of iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, ios13

In latest iOS 13 release, there are 2 major updates for Core Location & Core Bluetooth frameworks. User has updates in regard with permissions of the app.

Following link explain about the update:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background

https://medium.com/@arora.malika9/whats-new-in-core-location-in-ios-13-1275351686bd

https://medium.com/q42-engineering/apple-location-permission-ios13-1e0e59002889

https://gimbal.com/ios-13-location-permissions/

https://blog.estimote.com/post/186160021855/get-ready-for-ios-13-bluetooth-and-location

In the following 3 methods iBeacon triggers are delivered in the application depending on the state of the app:

1. When app is in foreground / background state:

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {

   }

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {

   }
2. When app is in awakened from terminated / suspended state:

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
             let dataForLocation = launchOptions? 
             [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location] as? [String: Any]
             if dataForLocation != nil {

   ```
          }
   ```

   }

Project Settings are as follows:

1. Targets -> Signing & Capabilities -> Background Modes -> Location updates, Background fetch & Remote notifications is already enabled
2. In Info.plist following are present:

```html
    
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses bluetooth</string>
    
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses peripheral</string>
    
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses location services</string>
    
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses location services</string>
    
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses location services</string> 
    
    <key>allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates</key>
    <true/>
    
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
     <string>bluetooth-central</string>
     <string>fetch</string>
     <string>location</string>
     <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

Am I missing any other support required for iOS 13? There is random event generation & no stability.

Comment: Can you please be very specific about exactly what you are witnessing  that is unexpected and the specific conditions when it happens?  The statement "There is random event generation & no stability" is too vague to provide concrete answers.

Comment: @davidgyoung, on lower versions iBeacon events triggered well. On versions 12 & 13 events not triggered when app is in suspended / terminated state.

Comment: So it works fine when the screen is on and visible, yes?   Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "suspended state"?  Do you receive no callbacks whatsoever in this case?

Comment: No call backs as mentioned in the above case of entry or exit get called. But in lower versions the code works in all states of the app

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "suspended state"?

Comment: Suspended - The app is in the background, but no code is being executed. 
App in background for a very long time. No interaction.

Comment: Following this video update API's too. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705

But app does not get entry event when app is in terminated state. In background state it works.